# estoy haciendo un proyecto en react y cuando hago "npm start", en la barra de la url sale localhost:3000 mas el nombre del repo del trabajo?. Gracias

Tags: reactjs

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con react, el cual lo tengo en un repo mio.

Al hacer "npm start" (la compilacion y todo el proceso sale ok), en la URL del navegador (Chrome) sale localhost:3000 mas el nombre del repo, donde tengo el proyecto???

Comment: no entiendo del todo la pregunta pero el proyecto está en el mismo sitio donde haces npm start

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Disculpa, pero no es del todo clara la pregunta. Tienes el código local clonado de un repo remoto, lo abres con VSC y corres `npm start`. En la salida te dice cuál es la URL donde puedes ver corriendo tu proyecto y por eso tiene la URL con el nombre del proyecto al final. Entonces, ¿cuál es la duda con eso?

Comment: Esto no es un foro y no funciona igual. Abajo sólo van los intentos de respuesta, puedes es [edit] tu pregunta y aclarar lo que haga falta, pero abajo no tienes que poner nada a menos que tú mismo encuentres la respuesta. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Y pues, borra la no-respuesta de abajo, por favor :)

Comment: El proyecto se ejecuta en tu pc, no sale a internet, pero en tu red local puedes acceder desde otro pc, con http://tu_ip:3000 ej. http://192.168.0.1:3000; Si quieres sacarlo a internet, una opción es subir los ficheros estáticos a un servidor web en la nube, dichos ficheros estáticos se generan ejecutando: npm run build